# Is there a way to see what a Flowable expression evaluates to?

Tags: java, el, activiti, bpmn, camunda

I am having a bit of a problem, I have an expression which evaluates to true when I use it in an xhtml page but it doesn't seem to evaluate to true when using it in an Activiti sequence flow.

My question is, can I somehow see what an Activiti expression evaluates to?
See below my expression please:

```
${activitiHelper.calendarMinusDays(7).before(activitiHelper.getProcessInstanceVariable('entity',execution.id).createdDate)}
```

Could it be that Activiti doesn't support the java.util.Date.before() method?
Thanks in advance for any advice! :)